# How can i implement Generic Access Profile (GAP) in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to implement 3D Synchronization Profile (3DSP) v.1.0.3 for Windows 10 (spec: https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=308939) to "fake" 3D display. I own 120Hz monitor and i want to create active shutter glass synchronizer with bluetooth app.

I need to implement GAP profile as described in spec.
Is this possible in Windows 10 using C# or Python?

I already tried some Python libraries (bleak, pybluez) but non of them have functionality to create GAP.

In C# i see that Windows 10 provided new API for that as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN

But still i think i cannot use this for creating GAP:

```
The following Services are reserved by the system and cannot be published at this time:
Device Information Service (DIS)
Generic Attribute Profile Service (GATT)
Generic Access Profile Service (GAP)
Human Interface Device Service (HOGP)
Scan Parameters Service (SCP)
Attempting to create a blocked service will result in BluetoothError.DisabledByPolicy being returned from the call to CreateAsync.
```

Is there any software or even programmable hardware (usb bluetooth dongle?) to achieve this?
Maybe if there is solution for Linux it can be used in Windows with HyperV and Docker?

Comment: You do not need to implement GAP because it is implemented on system level. Start right from the profile you need. You can use Bluetooth Framework for such things (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm).

Comment: Is there any free equivalent?

Comment: 32feet probably.

Comment: Thanks, will test it.

Comment: 32feet does not support BLE for Windows at this moment:
https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/wiki/Bluetooth-Low-Energy

Comment: Then there is no free lib for BLE except WinRT API: Start from this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice